# Шифрование sha1 в Golang

Tags: golang, sha1, шифрование, md5

Добрый вечер!

Никак не могу разобраться с шифрованием в Go.
Делаю все как в примере:

```
h := sha1.New()
io.WriteString(h, "123456")
fmt.Println(h.Sum(nil))
```

Все ок, на выходе вижу обещанный массив `byte`.
Но при попытке преобразовать его в строку

```
var result = string(h.Sum(nil))
```

Получается какая-то абракадабра, никак не могу понять, в чем дело...

Comment: Обратите внимание, SHA, MDx и base64 - это не шифрование, а хэширование. Недостаток - в возможности подбора оригинала при получении хэша, если на входе вы используете что-то типа пароля.

Comment: sha и md5 - хеширование. Подобрать оригинал можно перебором, хотя и сложно. base64 - это просто кодирование (не путать с шифрованием)  и его результат напрямую конвертируется в исходное состояние.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для подобного преобразования я использую следующий код:

```
func foo(someStr string) string {
    h := md5.New()
    h.Write([]byte(someStr))    
    return fmt.Sprintf("%x", h.Sum(nil))
}
```

*Обновление*. Можно еще и так делать:

```
func ByteToBase64(value []byte) string {
    return base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(value)
}
```

Comment: Ура-а-а-а, заработало! )
Спасибо!